# Print through flex / flash builder mobile application for ios

Tags: apache-flex, printing, air, flash-builder4.5

I have to allow user to print through my application. I am creating application for ios using flash builder 4.5.1

Here is the code for it:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.printing.*;

            // Create a PrintJob instance.
            private function doPrint():void
            {
                // Create an instance of the FlexPrintJob class.

                    var printJob = new FlexPrintJob(); // calls the dialog

                    if(printJob.start())  // Starts when the user presses ok
                    {

                        printJob.addObject(dashPreview,FlexPrintJobScaleType.MATCH_WIDTH); // the object you want to add, and the scaling you want to apply
                        printJob.send(); // Send everything to the printers.        
                    } 
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="dashPreview" x="334" y="110" text="naveed mansuri">

    </s:Label>

    <s:Button id="myButton" x="19" y="215" width="729" label="Print" click="doPrint();">

    </s:Button>     
</s:View>
```

But Whan I run this application and clicl on print, I got following error box of errors:-

```
Error: Error #2055: The print job could not be started. at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.printing::PrintJob/start()
    at mx.printing::FlexPrintJob/start()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\printing\FlexPrintJob.as:200]
    at views::PrintHomeView/doPrint()[C:\Documents and Settings\naveedmansuri\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\Print\src\views\PrintHomeView.mxml:20]
    at views::PrintHomeView/__myButton_click()[C:\Documents and Settings\naveedmansuri\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\Print\src\views\PrintHomeView.mxml:34]
```

What wrong in this code? Is print class is not mobile optimized?
I have to print only a label text.
Sincere request to get me out of this issue. I have a release date soon for this application.

Answer (score 0):

From the [LiveDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html):

> **Mobile Browser Support**: This class is not supported in mobile
>   browsers.
>
> *AIR profile support*: This feature is supported on all desktop
>   operating systems, but it ***is not supported on mobile devices*** or AIR
>   for TV devices. You can test for support at run time using the
>   PrintJob.isSupported property. See AIR Profile Support for more
>   information regarding API support across multiple profiles.

Only way to print on mobile devices is through an AIR Native Extension.

Comment: Can you tell me whihc AIR Native extension I have to use?

Comment: No, sorry. I was looking for one last week and was unable to find one. That would be the only way to do it, though.